# Algorithm Analysis question from Skiena's Algorithm Design Manual

Tags: algorithm, math, discrete-mathematics

I am stuck on this question... [image]from Skiena's algorithm design manual.

This is part of the solution[image] provided on his [companion site](http://www.algorist.com/algowiki/index.php/TADM2E_2.2).

I am unclear as to why adding 1 is necessary for the summation of k=j to i+j. I understand that the summation can further be broken down into the summation of k=1 to i+j minus the summation of k=1 to j, but I do not understand why 1 has to be added.

Comment: That's because there are `i+j - j + 1` numbers from `j` to `i+j`

Comment: Please include the code you referring within your question. You can easily format them as code. Links to other sides are not ideal.

Answer (score 0):

Let:

**S is the sum of k from j to i+j**.

We can break it as subtraction of summation i.e. s1(from k = 1 to k = i+j) and s2(from k = 1 to k = j-1).

**s1 = i+j** (summation from 1 up to i+j)

**s2 = j-1** (summation from 1 up to j-1)

S = s1 - s2

S = (i+j) - (j-1)

**S = i + j - j + 1**

Hope you get it...